# How to send table data to the controller after click in submit button

Tags: html, spring

I have a table where data are poulate from database, I want to update the table after giving value into the Text1,Text2 and send it to the controller, how could i do this.

html

```
<form  action="/update" method="post" > 
        <table border="1">
            <thead> 
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="id"> ID </th>
                    <th data-field="details"> Details </th>
                    <th data-field="report"> Report </th>
                    <th data-field="value"> value </th>
                    <th data-field="destination"> Destination </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <c:forEach items="${List2}" var="as">
            <tr >
                <td>${as.id}</td>
                <td>${as.rulDetails}</td>
                <td>${as.rulName}</td>
                <td><input type="text" name ="Text1">
                <td>${as.rulValue}</td>
                <td><input type="text" name ="Text2">
                </td>
            </tr>                           
            </c:forEach>    
</table>
            <input type="submit" value="Update"></input>
```

Here is my servlet for update table, i did't write anything because i don't understand how could i do this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") AssignmentDetails asd  ModelMap model) {  

       //what i should write here..?


    return "hello"; 
}
```

Please tell me/help me what i need to do? What i need to modified.?Please give me an advice or help to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/) tutorial.

You can use the spring taglibs.

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="SpringWeb" action="/update">
   <form:input path="Text1" type="text" />
   <form:input path="Text2" type="text" />
</form:form>
```